# Maven builds for different environments using xml templating - differences too complicated for simply properties or token replacement

Tags: java, xml, maven

I am trying to come up with a solution for managing XML configuration files for multi-environment builds that does not involve maintaining one configuration file for each environment. By XML configuration file, I mean XML files used at run-time, ie web.xml, and not the POM itself. I could of course maintain a separate XML file for each environment and then define a Maven property that contains the different file path and then have separate Maven profiles that point to the correct file path for the profile to correctly package them into the WAR/EAR/etc based upon environment, but I would prefer a different solution.

Like I am suggesting in the title, the differences are not something that can be accomplished by a simple token replacement - completely different XML structures are required in different environments. I originally tried using the maven Antrun plugin to run Ant's xmltask to add/remove/delete nodes via Xpath, but this is overly verbose and complicated to maintain, especially considering this plugin's inability to properly handle XML namespaces in a non-verbose manner.

Ideally, the XML file would like a normal template file, ie:

```
<x:if environment="production">
     <a b="c">
       <d>
     </a> 
</x:if>
<x:else>
     <g />
</x:else>
```

At build time, ie during package or process-resources phases, the resultant XML file would contain only one set of XML or the other (in this example).

Note how, like I mentioned above, the node structures are completely different between environments.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

There is "[bean definition profiles](http://spring.io/blog/2011/02/11/spring-framework-3-1-m1-released/#enter-bean-definition-profiles)".

Basic usage:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:c="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="businessService"
       class="com.c...s.springthreeone.business.SimpleBusinessServiceImpl"/>

    <beans profile="dev,qa">
        <bean id="constructorBean"
          class="com.gordondickens.springthreeone.SimpleBean"
              c:myString="Constructor Set"/>

        <bean id="setterBean"
          class="com.gordondickens.springthreeone.SimpleBean">
            <property name="myString" value="Setter Set"/>
        </bean>
    </beans>

    <beans profile="prod">
        <bean id="setterBean"
          class="com.gordondickens.springthreeone.SimpleBean">
            <property name="myString" value="Setter Set - in Production YO!"/>
        </bean>
    </beans>
</beans>
```

Add to your WEB.XML for selecting active:

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>spring.profiles.active</param-name>
  <param-value>prod</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Or jUnit Tests:

```
@ActiveProfiles(profiles = "dev")
```

Or you could set Environment Variable/JVM Parameter:

```
SPRING_PROFILES_DEFAULT=dev
```

Oryou could set selected profile with maven:

```
mvn -DSPRING_PROFILES_DEFAULT=dev
```

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding. I want to change contents of the web.xml ITSELF (and other similar files) based upon the environment, not to control the instantiation of Java classes or Injected properties.

Comment: @GreenieMeanie, add another answer

Answer (score 0):

You can create basic maven project with common stuff and create two projects with different `web.xml` and other files.
Use [maven web-app overlays](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/overlays.html)  function to marge resources, in that case you will have one project with common files and two other projects - each for required env.

You could even make these projects as modules of another project and run required depending on maven profile.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but this still isn't what I am asking for in the original question.